# 301 redirect through Apache .CONF file

Tags: apache

I would like to ask you a question.
Is it possible to redirect the old URL to a new url (old sub-page to new sub-page) (301 redirects) in Apache through etc/apache/sites-available/...conf file?

I found this code. I am not sure if it works. The problem is that it's not a redirection of sub-pages.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
Redirect 301 /oldlocation http://www.domain2.com/newlocation
</VirtualHost>
```

I need help with the 301 redirection code that I can place in .conf file.

Comment: this question is better asked at https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com